# Interior Points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I'm learning analysis using the Rudin's book, and sometimes the definitions make me wonder and leave me quite puzzled...

So, interior points: a set is open if all the points in the set are interior points. However, if a set has a point inside it, surely it will always have a neighborhood (or a small ball) that will be contained in the set. So, what keeps all the points from being interior points? (points inside the set I mean)

Also, second question: is a limit point an interior point?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your other question: a limit point of a set $A$ **can** be an interior point of $A$, but it need not be. Let $A=[0,1)$ with the usual topology, for instance. Then $\frac12$ is a limit point of $A$ that is also an interior point of $A$, and $0$ and $1$ are limit points of $A$ that are not interior points of $A$. For another example, in the real line with the usual topology **every** point is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$, and **no** point is an interior point of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: just one question, how is 1/2 a limit point of A?

Comment: Also, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user65165: You’re welcome! $\frac12$ is a limit point of $[0,1)$ because every interval $\left(\frac12-\epsilon,\frac12+\epsilon\right)$ contains a point (indeed, infinitely many points) of $A$ other than $\frac12$ itself. In fact, the set of limit points of $[0,1)$ is precisely the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 7):

> However, if a set has a point inside it, surely it will always have a neighborhood (or a small ball) that will be contained in the set.

Not true: consider $\Bbb R$ with Eucledian topology and a set $A = \{0\}$. No balls of positive radius around $0$ are contained in $A$.

Answer (score -1):

$A$ be a closed set and $D = \overline{A^\circ}$. Prove that $D^\circ=A^\circ$.

Notation:

$A^\circ$: interior of $A$.
$\overline{A}: $ closure of $A$.